# How can I get proportional bubble sizes from R bubbleGoogleMaps?

Tags: r, bubble-chart, plotgooglemaps

I would like to use `bubbleGoogleMaps` to create a map of `spatialpoints` with bubbles sized proportionally to their individual value. Anyways, that is what`bubbleGoogleMaps` is promising according to the documentation.

However, I realized that the **bubble sizes are *not* propotional to their individual values, but only to their bin they fall into**.

By default `bubbleGoogleMaps` only uses 5 bins based on the quantiles, which easily results in very misleading maps, as the following example will demonstrate:

```
library("plotGoogleMaps")

data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse)<-~x+y 
proj4string(meuse) <- CRS('+init=epsg:28992')

# we want to see one gigantic bubble for the first observation
# --> let's augment its value to 10000:
meuse$zinc[1] <- 10000 

# However, there is no gigantic bubble in the following bubbleGoogleMaps! 
# --> Bubbles are NOT proportional to their individual values!!!
m <- bubbleGoogleMaps(meuse,
                      zcol='zinc',
                      max.radius = 100,
                      filename='myMap.htm')
```

---

So I tried to create a workaround by augmenting the number of bins (=option 'key.entries') from 5 to 20:

```
keys <- signif(quantile(meuse$zinc,
                        probs = seq(0, 1, length.out=20),
                        na.rm=T,
                        names=F),3);keys
```

However, this workaround does not work, we get an error here:

```
m <- bubbleGoogleMaps(meuse,
                      zcol='zinc',
                      max.radius = 100,
                      key.entries=keys, 
                      filename='myMap.htm')
```

---

**Any ideas how to create a `bubbleGoogleMap` with (individually) proportional bubbles?**

**Or does anyone know how to make the workaround with the option `key.entries` work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [author](http://www.grf.bg.ac.rs/fakultet/pro/e?nid=168) of the `plotGoogleMaps` package solved my problem. He confirmed that `bubbleGoogleMaps` works with bins indeed.

For **augmenting the number of bins** to 20 we need to set `key.entries` to

```
key.entries= quantile(meuse@data[, 'zinc'], (1:20)/20)
```

or **for unique values**

```
key.entries= unique(sort(meuse$zinc))
```

This is what I originally wanted. However, the legend is now getting very messy/massive or even not functioning anymore...